# Variables inside the for loop are not recognised by the loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, variables, for-loop

The variable `z` which should increase the value of `x` is not getting recognised while the variables `y` and `x` do.
With the variable 'z' set to 3, i was expecting the value of x to get increased by 3 every time the loop ran but instead it increases by 1 every time.

```
def lists(x, y, z):
    numbers = []
    for x in range(x, y):
        print "At the top x is %d" % x
        numbers.append(x)

        x += z
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom x is %d" % x

    print "The numbers: "

    for num in numbers:
        print num

lists(int(raw_input("Starting Value: ")), int(raw_input("Ending Value: ")),
int(raw_input("Increment Amount: ")))
```

Comment: `for x in ...` sets `x` to the next value each iteration. It doesn't matter what you do in the body of the loop to `x`, the `for` statement will still make that assignment each time, replacing whatever `x` was pointing at before.

Comment: You didn't specify what values you entered, nor what output you got or what output you expected; please make this a proper [MCVE].

Comment: And if you wanted to produce numbers with a step size, why not just use `numbers = range(x, y, z)`?

Comment: So the answer is the same: the `for` loop is driven by the `range()` output. Altering `x` won't change the `range()` list values, so `for` sets `x` to the next value and ignores anything you do with `x` in the loop.

Comment: To make `range()` use a larger step size than 1, pass in `z` as the third parameter instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for` loop is a [for-each construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop); it takes the sequence produced by `range()` and sets `x` to each value from that sequence in turn.

Whatever you do with `x` *in the loop body* doesn't make a difference here, because `for` doesn't care what you do with `x` afterwards.

If you want to use `z` as a step size, pass it to `range()` directly:

```
for value in range(x, y, z):
    numbers.append(value)
```

or simply drop the `for` loop altogether, because in Python 2 `range()` creates a list object:

```
numbers = range(x, y, z)
```

If you wanted to simulate a C-like `for` loop (where you *can* alter the loop variable in the loop body), use a *`while` loop* instead:

```
while x < y:
    x += z
    print x
```

Comment: Thank you so much.